# sql - unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't for the life of me find the error here? It's on this line

```
"INSERT INTO `users`(`email`,`password`)
                    `   VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email'])."', md5(md5($_POST['email']).$_POST['password']).')";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a quote or two, and threw in an extra backquote.

```
"INSERT INTO `users`(`email`,`password`)
                   VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email'])."', ".md5(md5($_POST['email']).$_POST['password'])."')";
```

That being said, this should probably go on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and for the solution.